# How are polkadot bootnodes set up?

Tags: polkadot, nodes, networking, bootnode

I'm trying to set up my own public blockchain and have been running into issues when setting up a bootnode to be accessible over DNS rather than IP4. Based on the Polkadot chain specification, their bootnodes are all set up using DNS, like:

```json
{
  "name": "Polkadot",
  "id": "polkadot",
  "chainType": "Live",
  "bootNodes": [
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-0.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWEPmjoRpDSUuiTjvyNDd8fejZ9eNWH5bE965nyBMDrB4o",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-1.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWLvcA24g6sT9YTaQyinwowMbLF5z7iMLoxZpEiV9pSmNf",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-2.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWDhp18HYzJuVX2jLhtjQgAhT1XWGqah42StoUJpkLvh2o",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-3.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWEsPEadSjLAPyxckqVJkp54aVdPuX3DD6a1FTL2y5cB9x",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-4.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWFfG1SQvcPoUK2N41cx7r52KYXKpRtZxfLZk8xtVzpp4d",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-5.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWDmQPkBvQGg9wjBdFThtWj3QCDVQyHJ1apfWrHvjwbYS8",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-6.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWBKtPpCnVTTzD7fPpCdFsrsYZ5K8fwmsLabb1JBuCycYs",
    "/dns/polkadot-connect-7.parity.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWP3BsFY6UaiLjEJ3YbDp6q6SMQgAHB15qKj41DUZQLMqD",
    "/dns/p2p.0.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWHsvEicXjWWraktbZ4MQBizuyADQtuEGr3NbDvtm5rFA5",
    "/dns/p2p.1.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWQz2q2UWVCiy9cFX1hHYEmhSKQB2hjEZCccScHLGUPjcc",
    "/dns/p2p.2.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWNHxjYbDLLbDNZ2tq1kXgif5MSiLTUWJKcDdedKu4KaG8",
    "/dns/p2p.3.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWGJQysxrQcSvUWWNw88RkqYvJhH3ZcDpWJ8zrXKhLP5Vr",
    "/dns/p2p.4.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWKer8bYqpYjwurVABu13mkELpX2X7mSpEicpjShLeg7D6",
    "/dns/p2p.5.polkadot.network/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSRjL9LcEQd5u2fQTbyLxTEHq1tUFgQ6amXSp8Eu7TfKP",
    "/dns/cc1-0.parity.tech/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSz8r2WyCdsfWHgPyvD8GKQdJ1UAiRmrcrs8sQB3fe2KU",
    "/dns/cc1-1.parity.tech/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWFN2mhgpkJsDBuNuE5427AcDrsib8EoqGMZmkxWwx3Md4"
  ],
  "...": "..."
```

My question is, how do they set up these bootnodes to listen on a custom domain? How does that look like on the nginx side?

I've tried setting mine up by running the node with the params:

```
--ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --name "Bootnode 1" --pruning archive --public-addr="/dns/{CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/tcp/443"
```

and my nginx config like:

```
server {

  server_name {CUSTOM_DOMAIN};

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:30333;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /ws {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9944;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.pem;

  ssl_session_cache shared:cache_nginx_SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";

}
```

But when I try to run other nodes and connect to the bootnode, they are unable to. I am completely clueless whether the problem I have is on my nginx or node configuration or both.  If you know something about how Polkadot hosts their bootnodes or know how to do it, I'd appreciate it.